# Exclude certain taxonomies from url reachbility

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have the following structure example.com/taxonomy/term/334 and there are several terms that I don't want to be reachable by domain.

I use the autopath module, so for example it could be I want example.com/status/green and example.com/status/red so to say every example.com/status/* to be reachable, but example.com/media/blu-ray and example.com/media/dvd or example.com/media/* not.

Any ideas how this can get realized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/comment/48808#comment-48808) to change the access control for taxonomy/term/%